# How can I easily change tf-idf similarity dataframe using apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply, tf-idf

I'm using Python 3.
I am doing TF_IDF, and I record more than 80% of results.
But for is too slow. because shape is 51,336 x 51,336.
How can you create dataframes faster without using for statement.
It's taking 50 minutes now.
I want to make a dataframe like this.

> [column_0],[column_1],[similarity]
>   index[0], column[0], value
>   index[0], column[1], value
>   index[0], column[2], value
>   ....
>   index[100], column[51334], value
>   index[100], column[51335], value
>   index[100], column[51336], value
>   ...
>   index[51336], column[51335], value
>   index[51336], column[51336], value

```
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
indices = pd.Series(df.index, index=df['index_name'])
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(df['text'])
similarity = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'similarity'])

for n in range(len(cosine_sim)):
    for i in list(enumerate(cosine_sim[n])):
        if i[1] > 0.8 and i[1] < 0.99:
            similarity = similarity.append({'column_0': indices.index[n],'column_1': indices.index[i[0]],'similarity': i[1]},ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of parallelize a job, unfortunately there is no-way to parallelize/distribute access to the vocabulary that is need for these vectorizers.
Hence you choose the alternative hack for that. By using the **hashingvectorizer**.
well for this scikit docs provide an example using this vectorizer to train a classifier in batches.
 https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html.

Hope this will help you